# Real time Microphone memory stream capture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

is there any way to send Microphone audio stream to service side in real time?

I am using WCF service at the middle layer where I am converting audio to text using system.speech. It is working fine if I am sending wav file as memory stream but how it possible in a live scenario using the microphone?